# How does the stateless nature of HTTP makes system scalable?

Tags: http

Fielding Dissertation on "Architectural Styles and the Design of Network-based Software Architectures" states on page 78-79 that communication between client and server should be stateless. It further says "This constraint induces the properties of visibility, reliability, and scalability." 
Moreover, it says, "Scalability is improved because not having to store state between requests allows the server component to quickly free resources, and further simplifies implementation because the server doesn’t have to manage resource usage across requests."

Now-a-days we need "stateful-ness" in almost every other application, how is that statelessness nature of HTTP still beneficial in scalability then?

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This has pretty much nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @black That's why it's posted in "http" section.

Comment: Where did you read that HTTP was designed for scalability through statelessness?

Comment: @CodeCaster Fielding Dissertation states on page 78-79 that communication between client and server should be stateless. It further says "This constraint induces the properties of visibility, reliability, and scalability." "Scalability is improved because not having to store state between requests allows the server component to quickly free resources, and further simplifies implementation because the server doesn’t have to manage resource usage across requests."
Now-a-days we need "stateful-ness" in almost every other application, how is that statelessness nature of HTTP still beneficial then?

Comment: Can you edit that into the question?

Comment: @Pekka웃 sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nowadays we need "stateful-ness" in almost every other application

We do indeed in "most" applications. There are a *lot* of applications that provide a mere CRUD interface to some persistent storage.

That has, however, very little to do with the architecture of said applications, or rather, how they talk to their back-end. A client, generally hosting some user interface, which talks through some layer to some service in order to let the back-end execute some actions (either CRUD or RPC).

It's about the communication to and from this service. *That*'s what is stateless. This means that each message from the client to the service contains enough information to let the service execute the desired action. That's all what REST stands for.

This means that the server doesn't need to know anything about the origin of the connection made by the client. There is no permanent connection needed from client to server. There is no "metadata" hidden in the connection, or in the session this connection entails.

This means that you can easily scale horizontally: when your server continuously reaches its client connection limits or other resource limits, you can simply add another server, so you can serve more clients.

Now given HTTP is inherently stateless (apart from session emulation using cookies and serverside storage), it lends itself ultimately as the transport layer for REST services.